# Referring to object via variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

My object is as below

```
var masterData = {      
    "region":[
            {"key":"1","value":"AMS"},
            {"key":"2","value":"APJ"},
            {"key":"3","value":"EMEA"}
    ]
};

var key = 'region';
var strList = 'masterData.'+key;

$.each($(strList), function(i, row) {
    alert(row.key); 
});
```

It's not entering the loop, but if I replace the variable with the actual object, it works. For example:

```
$.each($(masterData.region), function(i, row) {
    alert(row.key);     
});
```

I want to do the same via a variable, like the first one. What am I missing here?

Comment: This is **not** JSON. This is an object literal. Unfortunately many people make the mistake to confuse object literals with JSON. See [There is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this worked

```
    $.each($(eval(strList)), function(i, row) {
    alert(row.key);     
    });
```

Comment: I don't think they should use `eval` for this, its really unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

Since an object is considered an associative array, properties can be accessed by key in this manner:

```
var key = 'region';
var strList = masterData[key];
```

[Good Overview of Objects as Associative Arrays](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html)